# Why won't my grunt task work - emailBuilder

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am trying to run a simple bare bones grunt task and it is not working. I installed using npm install from this package:

```js
{
  "name": "ent-nmo-fasg-younger-mills-em-1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-email-builder": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

Then in my Gruntfile.js I have added this code:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
 grunt.initConfi({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
  emailBuilder: {
    files : [{
     expand: true,
     src: ['dev/*.html'],
     dest: 'dist/',
   }]
  }
 });
 
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-email-builder');
 
 grunt.registerTask('dist',['emailBuilder']);
};
```

The error I am getting in terminal after trying to run "grunt dist" is:

Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR

> > TypeError: undefined is not a function
> >     Warning: Task "dist" not found. Used --force, continuing.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was a simple spelling error in the grunt configuration.